# If $z > 3$ is an integer, is there an integer $a > z$ such that $(z-j) \mid (a-j)$ for every $1 \leq j \leq z-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is:

If $z>3$ is an integer, is there an integer $a > z$
such that
$$(z-j) \mid (a-j)$$
for every $1 \leq j \leq z-1$?

Comment: Check for $a=z!+z$

Comment: Indeed a right choice.

Comment: I believe the smallest such $a > z$ is $a = z+\text{lcm}(1,2,3,\ldots,z-1)$.

Comment: Is it $a=(z-1)!+z$

Comment: In fact, if (z - j) divides (a - j), then (z - j) divides (a - j) - (z - j) = a - z. So a - z is a multiple of z - j for all 1 <= j <= z-1.

Comment: Yeah , for any natural number $k$, a=$z+k*lcm(1,2,3,...,(z-1))$ satisfies.

Comment: It would be useful to write an answer, so that the question will not remain in the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ be the integer that satisfies given conditions , then

$(z-j)|(a-j)$ for $j=1$ to $z-1$

I am substituting  $j$ from $z-1$ to $1$ in above

$\implies1|(a-z+1),2|(a-z+2),3|(a-z+3),\cdots,(z-1)|(a-z+(z-1))$

$\implies 1|(a-z),2|(a-z),3|(a-z),\cdots,(z-1)|(a-z)$

$\implies (a-z) = k*lcm(1,2,3,\cdots,z-1)$ for any natural number $k$

$\implies a=z+k*lcm(1,2,3,\cdots,z-1)$

Which satisfies all the conditions .

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Just a little suggestion: The existence of such $a$ is to be proved. So to begin with, it is better to leave it as simply a number (so that we can apply arithmetic operations to it) and finally prove that it indeed can be an integer.

Comment: @Brian is t okay now ?

Comment: It is a little longer than necessary. One could just say that $z$ satisfies the congruences $a\equiv j\pmod{z-j}$, and therefore $z+(z-1)!$ does.

Comment: @hanu Yes and thank you.

Comment: @Nicolas That is beautiful.